# Setting up different application instances under one DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

We have a custom java web app. We are setting it up in instances in different vps (different providers, different locations). We have for example:

```
Instance 1: http://server1/app1
Instance 2: http://server1/app2
Instance 3: http://server2/app3
```

Each instance is independent and self contained. We have several docens of this instances and will continue to add them.

My question is regarding the dns managment, as we want to map different subdomains to the instances.

```
client1.mypp.com  > http://server1/app1
client2.mypp.com  > http://server1/app2
client3.mypp.com  > http://server2/app3

clientN.mypp.com  > http://anyserver/appN
```

Right now we are adding the A records manually to the DNS records to relate subdomain to the ip. We will develop some code to do it using the API of the DNS provider.

Is this the most appropiate aproach? Should we use some kind of proxy instead? We expect to have thousands of isntances accros different servers. I am interested in perfomance and availability.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective approach would be to ditch the reliance on IP/port and use something inside your URL to direct you to the correct service.

client1.mypp.com app1 `http://server1/app1`

client2.mypp.com app2 `http://server1/app2`

This could be a load balancer or reverse proxy. See, e.g., nginx, haproxy, pound, etc.

[image]

Comment: Does using the proxy approach is effective even if the web servers are located in diffetent networks with different providers and locations?

Answer (score 0):

Well DNS won't be doing anything with ports. So even if you create A records, going to client1.mypp.com won't make your browser go to port 8080. You would have to browse to client1.mypp.com:8080.

What you want is to use Apache or similar in front of your java web app. With Apache mod_proxy and using VirtualHost you can achieve what you want.

Example of Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName client1.mypp.com
  ProxyPass / http://server1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse / http://server1:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I already manage the port with apache proxy. My question is over having one domain directing subdomains records to different server on different locations. Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar - tut tut tut... your post confuses things since it shows the ports... you need to make your post show the real state of things - complete. But the above example would resolve what you are trying to do then.