# Should i use DNS or Proxy for server resolution?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, reverse-proxy

We have a custom java web app. We are setting it up in instances in different vps (different providers, different locations).Each instance is independent and self contained. We have several docens of this instances and will continue to add them.

For example:

```
Instance 1: http://server1/app1
Instance 2: http://server1/app2
Instance 3: http://server2/app3
```

Currently, we are  mapping the subdomain using A records in the DNS of myapp. Then the server uses apache reverse proxy to map it to the app.

```
client1.myapp.com  > server1 >> http://server1/app1
client2.myapp.com  > server1 >> http://server1/app2
client3.myapp.com  > server2 >> http://server2/app3
clientN.myapp.com  > servern >> http://anyserver/appN
```

What is the difference or benefit of using a reverse proxy server?

For example:

```
client1.myapp.com  > proxyserver >> http://server1/app1
client2.myapp.com  > proxyserver >> http://server1/app2
client3.myapp.com  > proxyserver >> http://server2/app3
clientN.myapp.com  > proxyserver >> http://anyserver/appN
```

Are there any perfomance issues of using the proxy instead of the DNS records? As i see it all the request would go to the proxy server instead of going drectly to the server

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mixed things up (maybe after you have read some answers in your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/575089/setting-up-different-application-instances-under-one-dns)).

1. DNS will resolve :

   `client1.myapp.com` to `10.10.10.10`

   `client2.myapp.com` to `10.10.10.10`
2. Then, reverse proxy will redirect you to the right `App` regarding the request header
   :

   `http://client1.myapp.com` redirects to
   `http://client1.myapp.com/app1` (in fact `http://10.10.10.10/app1`)

   `http://client2.myapp.com` redirects to
   `http://client2.myapp.com/app2` (in fact `http://10.10.10.10/app2`)

---

`DNS` is not able to do point (2)

`Reverse Proxy` is not able to do point (1)

DNS and Reverse Proxy have not the same role, both are needed here.

So, for server name resolution use `DNS`, for your application redirection use a `Reverse Proxy`.

That is, in fact, just what you actually do :)